# Why is the function derivable.

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

I am doing the following exercise of Do Carmo's Differential Geometry:
A regular parametrized curve $\alpha$ has the property that all its tangent lines pass through a fixed point $p_0$.
Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is contained in the trace of a straight line.

Then we can put $$\alpha(s) + w(s)\alpha'(s)=p_0, \text{       (I)}$$ and deriving with respect to $t$, we have that $$\alpha'(s)+w'(s)\alpha'(s)+w(s)\alpha''(s)=0.$$

But how can I prove that $w$ -the function that gives the escalar that fulfill the condition (I)- is indeed a derivable function?

I need to use this argument in order to finish the proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solve $(I)$ for $w$.

Comment: But $\alpha'(s)$ is a vector function.

Comment: Use the scalar product: $\langle \alpha(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle + w(s)\langle \alpha'(s), \alpha'(s)\rangle =\langle p_0,\alpha'(s)\rangle.$